# Getting row count for a table in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, count, row

Can anyone tell me which is he better appraoch in MySQL whin it comes to finding the row count of a table: is it better to do

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_NAME
```

or to look up the row count in the table `TABLE` in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`?

This would be a frequent operation for calculating pagination counts for pages?

I should add that tables will only have a few thousand rows at most.

Thanks

Martin O'Shea.

Comment: For a few thousand rows select count(*) will work nearly instantaneously.

Answer (score 18):

In `MyISAM`, this query:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM    TABLE_NAME
```

is instant, since it's kept in the table metadata, so it's almost free to issue this query and it will always get the correct result.

In `InnoDB`, this query will count rows one-by-one which could take some time.

So if you don't need exact value of `COUNT(*)`, you may query `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.

Comment: I think that given that I need to calculate pagination using row count / pagination count, on InnoDB tables the best way is to use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA. Counting would only take milliseconds but that's still an overhead if several users are accessing the same table for browsing.

Answer (score 1):

I'd also consider using `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` and `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()` if you find `COUNT(*)` too slow.