# Joining two Mysql VIEWs takes a very long time

Tags: php, mysql, join, view

I have a textbox (for which I used jQuery auto-completion) in my PHP form where user can insert an actor/actress name and then by clicking "Search" button, a new window is opened showing list of movies by that actor/actress.

This is a query where I get movies by actor name:

```
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT c.movieName, c.castName, c.movieImdbId, f.year, f.posterLink FROM cast_movie as c JOIN film_info as f ON c.ImdbId = f.ImdbId WHERE c.castName = :q");
 $query->execute(array(':q' => $searchText ));
```

### My question:

The above query works fine if user select a name from auto-completion list. However I would like to enable user to write any name (even if he couldn't find from auto-completion list). For example, If user write "tom" in the textbox, and click on "search" button, I want to show list of all movies by all actors that their name containing word "tom".

For this purpose, I used `LIKE :q` and `':q' => '%' . $searchText . '%'` in the above query, but the query never ends!!(I think because `cast_movie` is a VIEW which is quite large (with 3 million rows) and joining this view with the other table takes a very long time (actually I waited for 10 minutes and it didn't finished yet).

Could someone kindly let me know if there is any way to fix this? (I read we can use index for joining very large tables, but I think it's not possible to define index for `cast_movie` since it is VIEW.)

### UPDATE:

Regarding comments, in order to provide more information:

`cast_movie` is a view which is made by joining "movie_roleNames" and "movies".

`movie_roleNames` is also a view which is made by joining two tables "Cast" and "nameRoles".

`film_info` is also a view that is made by joining two tables "movies" and "movies_info".

The structure of the above tables:

table **"movies"**: *Id, movieName, ImdbId(unique Id of movies), Rate, numVotes, year* (**indexes**: *ImdbId, movieName, year*)

table **"cast"**: *castName, castImdbID (unique Id of casts)* (**indexes**: *castName, castImdbID*)

table **"nameRoles"**: *Id, castImdbId, movieImdbId, role_Id*, (**indexes**: *movieImdbId, castImdbId*)

VIEW **"movie_roleNames"**: *Id, castName, castImdbId, movieImdbId* and the join statement was: `SELECT n.Id, c.castName, n.castImdbId, n.movieImdbId 
FROM nameRoles as n 
join Cast as c
ON n.castImdbId = c.castImdbID`

VIEW **"cast_movie"**: *Id, castName, castImdbId, movieImdbId, movieName* and the join statement was: `SELECT m.Id, r.castName, r.castImdbId, r.movieImdbId, m.movieName
FROM movie_roleNames AS r
JOIN movies AS m 
ON r.movieImdbId = m.ImdbId`

All ideas are highly appreciated,

Comment: Have you tried something like                "SELECT DISTINCT c.movieName, c.castName, c.ImdbId, f.year, f.posterLink FROM cast_movie as c LEFT JOIN film_info as f ON c.ImdbId = f.ImdbId WHERE c.castName LIKE '%".':q'."%' GROUP BY(c.movieName)"

Comment: Please post the `CREATE VIEW` Statement along with an Information about all indices defiend on your tables. Please provide the optput of an `EXPLAIN ...` as well.

Comment: @Benni: could you Please see my update? tnx

Comment: i suggest you use a pagination by adding `limit` to your query. since user won't see all of the data at once anyway.

Comment: @YohanesKhosiawan许先汉: I used pagination! but the query is executed before...sprry, maybe I didn't get your point

Comment: @ksealey:yes, I tried your query, the result is the same.. :(

Comment: for example if you use pagination per 100 entries, then you could try something like `limit 1,100`, `limit 101,100`, and so on.

Comment: @YohanesKhosiawan许先汉: actually I used pagination (2o movies per page), but I tested query in phpmyadmin.. I will try it now and let you know of the result :)

Comment: @YohanesKhosiawan许先汉: thanks a lot, it worked.. but still there are 2 problems: 1.It takes quite long time yet (about 40,50 sec to show results in each page)  2. I used rowcount in order to know the total number of rows (in order to use to calculate offset and page), e.g: `$query1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT c.movieName, c.castName, c.movieImdbId, f.year, f.posterLink FROM cast_movie as     c JOIN film_info as f ON c.movieImdbId = f.ImdbId WHERE c.castName LIKE :q"); $query1->execute(array(':q' => '%' . $searchText . '%')); $row_count = $query1->rowCount();`  plase see next comment too

Comment: @YohanesKhosiawan许先汉: sorry, it was too long, so I continue here: as you can see in the queries, when I calculated rowCount I didn't have offset yet, and this query is the one that is never ends.. do u have any suggestion?

Comment: I see.. if only you were going to show all data in your table/view, you may use this ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018336/getting-row-count-for-a-table-in-mysql. But in this case, I suggest that you just provide a Next button, which will try to get the next n rows from the view.. for example, if you use `limit 101,100` and actually your view only has 99 rows, it won't throw an error and just return a null result